# NaN error in javascript but correct result while debugging

Tags: javascript, nan

I need to calculate the percentage of an amount. however, I am having a weird problem. When the javascript runs uninterrupted, the display is always NaN.
However, when I debug the javascript and go line per line, I see no issue, and the display actually shows the right result.

I'm completely stumped at this point. here's my code:

```js
if(...){
   ...
} else{
  montant = new Number(montant);
  montantSal = new Number(montantSal);
  percent = (montant / montantSal) * 100.0;
}
//mettre la valeur au bon endroit
var rate = document.getElementsByName(baseName + rateSuffix)[0];
rate.value = percent;
rate = document.getElementsByName(baseName)[0];
rate.value = percent;
```

The value i am trying to display is percent. I can assure you montantSal is not null

Comment: Kinda pointless posting your code in a Stack Snippet when the code itself doesn't run standalone. I've edited it to be just a static code block.

Comment: Can we see the code where `montantSal` gets set?

Comment: Seeing as youve not shown us how `montant` or `montantSal` gets set, its impossible to answer this.

Comment: As an aside: to convert strings to numbers, use `Number(strVal)`, not `new Number(strVal)`.

Comment: yeah, sorry for the problems in my question, this is the first time i use the site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the contributions. in the end, using parsefloat works where new Number fails.

I still don't know why the browser debugger showed no problems, however.